# Images are gone from the backend of Magento but sitll on the frontend after SSL implementation

Tags: magento, ssl

I have implemented the SSL protocol in my Magento, everything is working fine but the products' images aren't shown in the backend, they still show up in the frontend.
If I modified the product page, the image will be gone. I tried uploading all my catalogs again with the path of the image on it and nothing else happens.

Can anybody help me?

I cannot attach an image though, I think I have described it correctly, there are no topics with this kind of issue.

Comment: Clear Magento caches, This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:
 1. login to Magento admin
 2. go to system->cache management.
 3. check all the cache options, select the option "Refresh" and click submit.
 4. below the cache table, you will find an option to clear magento images cache, do that.
 5. check if your issue is solved now.

If you have ssh access to the docroot, do the following:

1. go to the docroot, wher you can find the car directory when you execute an "ls" command.
2. execute this "rm -rf var/cache* var/session/*"

logout and log back to the admin panel and you should be able to see images now!